# Set maximal and minimal error values manually (different) for geom_errorbar in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I´m trying to specify error values with geom_errorbar in ggplot2. Actually I have a minimal and a maximal value that I want to show instead of error values. I tried to specify them by adding two columns to my input dataframe, one called lower and the other called upper. But the positive and negative error bars are still identical, when the values in the lower and upper columns are not.
I tried the following code in R:

```
df <- data.frame(
Genome = factor(c("A", "Y", "MT","A", "Y", "MT","A", "Y", "MT")),
resp = c(67.3, 33.9, 86.7, 7.2,6.3,13.3,24.9,61.8,0.0),
group = factor(c("african", "african", "african", 
"amerindian","amerindian","amerindian","european","european","european")),
upper = c(0.0, 44.8, 0.0, 0.0,10.0,0.0,0.0,71,0.0),
lower = c(0.0, 23.0, 0.0, 0.0,2.6,0.0,0.0,52.6,0)
)

    # Default bar plot
 p<- ggplot(df, aes(x=Genome, y=resp, fill=group)) + 
 geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
       position=position_dodge()) +
 geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=lower, ymax=upper), width=.2,
            position=position_dodge(.9)) 
 print(p)
```

Does anybody know what is the problem? When I change the values for lower and upper, more close to the resp values, it works, but these are not the values I need to plot.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object `df2 <- data.frame(…)` where … is your variable(s) and values or use `dput(df2)`. This will make it easy for others to help you by being able to test and verify solutions. These links may be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common error I've done many times.  When you specify `ymin` and `ymax` for `geom_errorbar`, you are specifying the *minimum and maximum y value itself*, not the +/- deviation *from the y value*.  This means that if you had a point with a y value of 5 and wanted to indicate 5 +/- 1, you would not specify `ymin = -1` and `ymax = +1`, but rather `ymin = y - 1` and `ymax = y + 1`.  Make sense?

Assuming `mi` and `ma` are signed values (meaning that `ma` are positive values and `mi` are negative values), your code should look something like this:

```
p<- ggplot(df2, aes(x=dose, y=len, fill=Ancestry)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black", 
       position=position_dodge()) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=len + mi, ymax=len + ma), width=.2,
            position=position_dodge(.9)) 
print(p)
```

Note the `ymax` and `ymin` are referencing your `y` aesthetic column within the `aes()`.

If your column `ma` and `mi` values are all positive, you'll need to adjust the signs accordingly within `aes()`.

Comment: Thank you chemdork123 for your answer! The thing is that what I actually want is to specify a maximal and minimal value, not an error value. So my max and min are different (not only in sign). I cannot figure it out how to specify that without the need to calculate each deviation from my Y value

Comment: Mind giving some more information here?  Not sure what you mean here.  If you're already specifying the value itself with `mi` and `ma` for each observation, then there should be no issue, as long as `ymin` < `ymax`.